# How to know the frequency of each observation in a column and sort them in r?

Tags: r, sorting

I have a column and each row is a string.
I want to find 
 1.The frequency of each sequence
 2.Sort the result by frequency from high to low
 3.If the frequency are the same for multiple strings, I sort them by alphabet of the sequence.

My data looks like

```
   ID             seq
1   1 BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB
2   2 BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB
3   3 BBBBBBIRRRRRRRR
4   4 BBBBBBITBBBBBBB
5   5 BBBBBBITBBBRBBX
6   6 BBBBBBITTTTBBCX
7   7 BBBBBBITTTTTTTT
8   8 BBBBBBOBBBBBBTX
9   9 BBBBBBOBBBBBBXB
10 10 BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB
11 11 BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB
12 12 BBBBBBIRRRRRRRR
13 13 BBBBBBITBBBBBBB
14 14 BBBBBBITBBBRBBX
15 15 BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB
16 16 BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB
17 17 BBBBBBIRRRRRRRR
18 18 BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB
19 19 BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB
20 20 BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB

ID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
seq<-c('BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB','BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB',  'BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB', 'BBBBBBIRRRRRRRR',  'BBBBBBITBBBBBBB',  'BBBBBBITBBBRBBX',  'BBBBBBITTTTBBCX',  'BBBBBBITTTTTTTT',  'BBBBBBOBBBBBBTX',  'BBBBBBOBBBBBBXB',  'BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB',  'BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB',  'BBBBBBIRRRRRRRR',  'BBBBBBITBBBBBBB',  'BBBBBBITBBBRBBX',  'BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB',  'BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB',  'BBBBBBIRRRRRRRR',  'BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB',  'BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB')
data.frame(ID,seq)
```

I want the result looks like this

```
sequence        Frequency
BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB 5
BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB 4
BBBBBBIRRRRRRRR 3
BBBBBBITBBBBBBB 2
BBBBBBITBBBRBBX 1
BBBBBBITTTTBBCX 1
BBBBBBITTTTTTTT 1
BBBBBBOBBBBBBTX 1
BBBBBBOBBBBBBXB 1
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think you want `aggregate(ID ~ seq, df, length)`.  It does the ordering for you.

Comment: `f <- table(df$seq); f[order(-f)]` The result is a named vector.

Comment: Thank you jogo. But still  But this makes the sorting by "seq alphabet" and "frequency". But I want to sort by frequency first then alphabet secondly.

Comment: @TerenceTien After `f <- f[order(-f)]` the vector is ordered by frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exert more control over the sorting and names you could use the following dplyr functions.

```
library(dplyr)
# assumes df is a data frame with seq and ID columns
df %>% 
  group_by(sequence = seq) %>% 
  summarize(frequency = length(ID)) %>% 
  arrange(-frequency)
```

Answer (score 3):

Can do this with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .N, by = seq][order(-N)]
```

It is worth noting that `data.table` consistently beats `dplyr` in terms of speed on different sample sizes:

[image]

Number of the top is how many times original sample was repeated.

Here is the code to reproduce:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
dtWay <- function(ID, seq) {
  dt <- data.table(ID, seq);
  setkey(dt, seq);
  return(dt[, .N, by = seq][order(-N)])
}
dplyrWay <- function(ID, seq) {
  df <- data.frame(ID, seq)
  res <- df %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(seq) %>% 
    dplyr::summarize(frequency = length(ID)) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(desc(frequency)) %>%
    dplyr::rename(sequence = seq)
  return (res)
}

N <- c(3, 4, 5, 6)
n <- 10^N

library(microbenchmark)
dev.off()
par( mfrow = c( 2, 2 ) )
res <- lapply(n, function(x) {

  ID <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
  ID <- rep(ID, times = x)
  seq<-c('BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB',  'BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB',   'BBBBBBIRRRRRRRR',  'BBBBBBITBBBBBBB',  'BBBBBBITBBBRBBX',  'BBBBBBITTTTBBCX',  'BBBBBBITTTTTTTT',  'BBBBBBOBBBBBBTX',  'BBBBBBOBBBBBBXB',  'BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB',  'BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB',  'BBBBBBIRRRRRRRR',  'BBBBBBITBBBBBBB',  'BBBBBBITBBBRBBX',  'BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB',  'BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB',  'BBBBBBIRRRRRRRR',  'BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB',  'BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB')
  seq  <- rep(seq, times = x)

  m <- microbenchmark( "data.table" = dtWay(ID, seq),
                       "dplyr" = dplyrWay(ID, seq),
                       times = 10, unit = "sc")

  a <- boxplot(m, main = x, xlab ="", ylab = "time")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I like `dplyr`.

```
install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)

df <- group_by(df, seq)
df <- count(df, seq)

count(df, seq)
Source: local data frame [9 x 2]

          seq     n
       (fctr) (int)
 1 BBBBBBIRBBRBBBB     4
 2 BBBBBBIRRRRRBBB     4
 3 BBBBBBIRRRRRRRR     3
 4 BBBBBBITBBBBBBB     2
 5 BBBBBBITBBBRBBX     2
 6 BBBBBBITTTTBBCX     1
 7 BBBBBBITTTTTTTT     1
 8 BBBBBBOBBBBBBTX     1
 9 BBBBBBOBBBBBBXB     1
```

That looks like your desired output, no?  Not sure why it there's only 4 counts of the first sequence, though.

Comment: Thank you. But this makes the sorting by "seq alphabet" and "frequency". But I want to sort by frequency first then alphabet secondly.